# First XHR request very slow in QML(javascript running on v8)

Tags: javascript, ajax, qml, qt5, qtquick2

I have a QML page (Qt Quick 2) that makes an XHR request to an external server. Right now the server is running on my local machine and the first time this request is made it takes ~1.5 seconds. Each subsequent request is under 100ms.

When I make this same request using a browser I get a response in under 10ms everytime, so I know the problem isn't there.

Here is the offending code. Any ideas?

```
function login(key) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var params = "Fob_num=" + key;
    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:9000/customer_login",true);

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if ( xhr.readyState == xhr.DONE) {
            if ( xhr.status == 200) {
                handleResponse(xhr.responseText);
            } else {
                console.log("error with login--status:  " + xhr.status)
                displayErr("Oops, something's wrong. Please try again.")
            }
        }
    }
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

The problem isn't with handleResponse() function, I've already tried replacing it with a console.log(“response”), and it still takes just as long. I also tried replacing localhost with my ip.

Comment: Have you checked for redirects happening? try "customer_login/", creating xmlhttprequest oobject should not take that kind of a duration. You can profile the function by logging x=new Date().getTime(); at each point on state change. Also try xml response.

Comment: I'm having this issue too; A Flask server is hosting a RESTful interface, content-type is application/json and other than that the issue is the same as the OP.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a dummy `XMLHttpRequest` instance in a dummy QML component that you asynchronously load with a `Loader`. Just an idea. Perhaps creating the first `XMLHttpRequest` instance takes long?

Comment: In my case, it isn't the instantiation of XMLHttpRequest that is taking time, but the call to XMLHttpRequest.open().